# Create an application's shortcut to launch it from Terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, tools

I need to launch an application created with ruby, python or perl from Terminal (without entering the directory), and keep it working.
This is an example :

When I go to the sqlnuke directory and start the application, it starts without problem like you see:

[image: sqlnuke sreenshot]

But when I create shortcut with the following command:

```
ln -s /opt/sqlnuke/sql.rb /usr/bin/sqlnuke
```

then I open Terminal and run `sqlnuke`, I get this error:

[image: sqlnuke error message]

Comment: Leave away the `-s` switch when linking and it should work...

Comment: Does `/opt/sqlnuke/sql.rb` import anything form its own directory (or another relative directory)?

Comment: I left away the  -s  but it is still not working

Comment: Yes I think it imports because in the error there is 'require'

Comment: Ah, see @glennjackman ' s answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You clearly have to `cd` to the proper directory first. 
`/usr/bin/sqlnuke` should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /opt/sqlnuke && ./sql.rb "$@"
```

If "sqlnuke" is for your use only, adding a script into /usr/bin is overkill. Add this to your ~/.bashrc:

```
sqlnuke() ( cd /opt/sqlnuke && ./sql.rb "$@" )
```